# AspNet Core 2.1 Website Azure AD B2C Example

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to implement Azure AD B2C for an AspNet Core 2.1 website. I'm not having any luck finding a good example with source code.

I did find https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/tree/master/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet, which might be a starting point, but given my current limited understanding of the various APIs it's not too helpful. For example, the properties in the AspNet Core 2.1 class AzureADB2COptions don't map all that well to the properties in the example's AzureAdB2COptions class, even though it looks like instances of both objects serve the same purpose in configuring the interaction with Azure's AD B2C system.

Has anyone come across some good examples they could pass along?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a code sample at [GitHub](https://github.com/chrispadgettlivecom/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNetCore21) for an ASP.NET Core 2.1 web application that authenticates an end user against Azure AD B2C using the ASP.NET Core 2.1 authentication middleware for Azure AD B2C, acquires an access token using MSAL.NET, and accesses a web API using this access token.

Comment: Wow! Thanx, @ChrisPadgett. I’ll need to study the example code, but I really appreciate you putting it together, and so quickly. Do you have a website/blog I can follow?

Comment: Follow up: when I clone and run the sample (only changing the local port specified in the RedirectUri parameter of appsettings.json), I get a redirect_uri_mismatch error from the "playground". When I click on the Settings button in the error page, the parameters (e.g., ClientId) don't match what's in appsettings.json. What else do I need to change to get the example to work?

Comment: BTW, the reason I want to get the example to work is that when I modify my own code to follow what you set up in the example -- which could obviously introduce errors -- I get an InvalidOperationException in SessionTokenCache::Load() on the _tokenCache.Deserialize() line. Details as follows: System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=Session has not been configured for this application or request.
  Source=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpContext.get_Session()
   (remainder trimmed)

Comment: The exception in my code base is occurring when the AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext is processed by the WrapOpenIdConnectEvent<>() method. The HttpContext.Session property of the context variable is initially in an "exception state", which then causes the SessionTokenCache::Load() method to fail. The first time that method is called, for the RedirectContext, succeeds without any problem.

Comment: With regards to the `redirect_uri_mismatch` error for the `fabrikamb2c` ("playground") tenant, you must run the web application on `https://localhost:44316/`, because this is the redirect URI that is configured for the client ID.

Comment: Thanx, that solved the problem with the example code. Now I just need to figure out why your code works and mine doesn't :)